# How do you manage an HTML element's focus() and blur() methods with snabbdom?

Tags: javascript, focus, blur, virtual-dom

The title pretty much says it all. With JavaScript and direct DOM element access you can simply do:

```
domElement.focus()
domElement.blur()
```

How do you do this through the virtual DOM in snabbdom? I think this is one of those cases in reactjs where you would just open the escape hatch and use refs. Is there something like this available with snabbdom?

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question.

Snabbdom's lifecycle hooks give you access to a virtual dom element's underlying real dom element via the `vnode.elm` property.

```
h('button', {
  update: {
    update (oldVnode, vnode) { vnode.elm.focus(); }
  }
});
```